# SDWebImage Does Not Accept StorageReference from Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase-storage, firebaseui, sdwebimage

I am trying to display data from Firestore and Google Storage on a UITableView.

I have a custom cell set up that has its own class called "PriceGuideCell"

I tried using the method shown on the Firebase website, after installing the FirebaseUI/Storage pod.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PriceGuideCell
                var item = itemData[indexPath.row]

      let reference: StorageReference = storageRef.child("test/\(item.itemID!).jpg")

                    cell.nameLabel?.text = item.name
                    cell.yearLabel?.text = String(item.year)
                    cell.boxnumLabel?.text = String(item.boxnum)
                    cell.itemImage?.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"))

                }
            }

            return cell
    }
```

The code above gives me an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'StorageReference' to expected argument type 'URL'
```

The code below, which uses the (reference).downloadURL, I have gotten to work, but I don't know if it is the best practice:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PriceGuideCell
            var item = itemData[indexPath.row]

            let imageURLRef = storageRef.child("test/\(item.itemID!).jpg")

            imageURLRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("There's an error:\(error)")
            } else {

                cell.nameLabel?.text = item.name
                cell.yearLabel?.text = String(item.year)
                cell.boxnumLabel?.text = String(item.boxnum)
                cell.itemImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"))


            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Is there something else I need to install for sd_setImage to accept StorageReference? Also, I have my Podfile targeted at 9.0. There was something [in the FirebaseUI readme](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS) about using 8.0. I don't know if this affects it or not, but 8.0 is too low for some of the other pods my project uses.

Comment: print (imageURLRef), see it print proper URL?

Comment: I get gs://projectname-1c14c.appspot.com/test/13377.jpg

Comment: Don't forget to import FirebaseStorageUI.

Comment: It's now ** FirebaseUI**.  AND you MUST use_frameworks in your pod file.

Answer (score 4):

After importing **FirebaseUI** and **SDWebImage**

```
import FirebaseUI
import SDWebImage
```

Firebase's **StorageReference** will work with the following method:

> UIImageView.sd_setImage(with: StorageReference, placeholderImage:
> UIImage)

As used below:

```
self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: Storage.storage().reference().child(url),
                           placeholderImage: nil)
```

You must have in Podfile

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Firestore'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
```

(or another combination, as explained here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS )

### AND!

you must

```
use_frameworks!
```

Confusingly some Firebase doco (2021) states you should avoid `use_frameworks!`.

However FirebaseUI will **NOT** work without `use_frameworks!` .

Comment: Trying this produces  Could not build Objective-C module 'FirebaseUI' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PriceGuideCell
                var item = itemData[indexPath.row]

      let referenceImage: StorageReference = storageRef.child("test/\(item.itemID!).jpg")
      let url = URL(string: referenceImage!)!
                    cell.nameLabel?.text = item.name
                    cell.yearLabel?.text = String(item.year)
                    cell.boxnumLabel?.text = String(item.boxnum)
                    cell.itemImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"))

                }
            }

            return cell
    }
```

Comment: The second block of code I posted works, the first does not, and is what I believe should work. For some reason, StorageReference is not accepted by SDWebImage, even though Firebase says it should work. 

See the [Downloading Images with FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) section of their website.

Comment: check answer print url

Comment: Problem was fixed by calling the right module.

Import FirebaseStorageUI. D'oh! Thank you Khawar for the help; it turned out to just be a simple mistake.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'StorageReference' to expected argument type 'String'

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import Firebase StorageUI framework in your class

```
import FirebaseStorageUI
```